# Variance of Beta hat derived when X is random

Tags: random-variables, expected-value, statistical-inference, variance

Consider the standard linear model $$y_i = \beta^TX_i+\varepsilon_i,\quad \begin{cases}i=1,\dots,n \\ \beta\in \mathbb R^p\\ E(\varepsilon_i\mid X_i) = 0\\ \mathrm{Var}(\varepsilon_i\mid X_i) = \sigma^2 \end{cases}$$
, where the target of inference is $\beta$. Assume that the empirical covariance $n^{-1}X^TX$ is invertible almost surely, where $X$ is the $n\times p$ matrix whose $i$th row is $X_i$. This is true, if for example, $X_i \overset{\text{i.i.d}}{\sim}\mathcal N(0,\Sigma)$ with $\Sigma$ non-singular and $n\geq p$. Let $\hat \beta$ be the least squares estimator, namely
$$\hat \beta = (X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$$

I'm trying to show that for a random X that

E($\underset{\sim}{\hat\beta}$)=$\underset{\sim}{\beta}$

Var($\underset{\sim}{\hat\beta}$)=$\sigma^2$E[$(X^TX)$<sup>-1</sup>$]$

I believe I was able to show that E($\underset{\sim}{\hat\beta}$)=$\underset{\sim}{\beta}$. However, I am pretty lost at how to get the variance. I was able to show that

Var($\underset{\sim}{\hat\beta}$)=$\sigma^2$$(X^TX)$<sup>-1</sup> for a fixed X.

But I don't know how I would get to the Variance of beta hat for a random X.

How do I get this Var($\underset{\sim}{\hat\beta}$)=$\sigma^2$E[$(X^TX)$<sup>-1</sup>$]$?

I would really appreciate some help showing me how to get there because I simply don't see how you would. Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: please provide context for what you are working on, otherwise people won't understand your question

Comment: @Andrew I apologize, I thought I did. I wanted help in understanding how to get the variance of beta hat for a random X, Var($\underset{\sim}{\hat\beta}$)=$\sigma^2$E[$(X^TX)$<sup>-1</sup>$]$. How do I get that?

Comment: I will add the context for you, please make sure to do it yourself in the future.

Comment: Usually, in the random regressor case, they will state something about the convergence of $X_{i}^{\prime} X_{i}$  as $i$ goes to $\infty$.  Also, if you can get it, check out Halbert White's "asymptotic theory for econometricians". I have the book in storage but I think I remember him covering that case quite nicely. Actually, the whole book is good.

Comment: @markleeds that's only necessary in high dimensional asymptotics. If $p$ is fixed like here, the statement doesn't even make sense.

Comment: @Andrew thank you so much, I will be sure to be more specific next time. Thank you again.

Comment: By the way, to do it for random design, the argument is just straightforward conditioning.

Comment: @Andrew: if an instance of $X$ is truly random and we want to take an expectation, then $\frac{X^{\prime}{X}}{n}$ needs to have an expectation. That expectation can only exist is one makes an assumption about the limit of $X^{\prime}X$.  Maybe if you show the straightforward conditioning argument, I'll see more clearly what you're referring to.

Comment: @markleeds the expectation clearly exists and is given by the covariance of $X_i$

Comment: Hi Andrew: It only clearly exists, if you make an assumption about $X^{\prime} X$. See Theorem 2.18 at this link ( its page 20 ). One needs to first "borrow" the book and then use the zoom button to see better. Or atleast I did !!!!! https://archive.org/details/asymptotictheory0000whit/page/20/mode/2up

Comment: @markleeds did you read the context I gave? The $X_i$ are iid with finite covariance.  This immediately implies $X^TX/n$ has expectation given by the covariance of $X_i$

Comment: @markleeds I just looked at white’s book. It is not the standard linear model setting, but something more general. In particular, note the assumptions I have written in the post. In any case, I can answer this question, but it really is straightforward

Comment: Hi Andrew: Yes, if $X_{i}$ are iid with finite covariance, then you're derivation below is fine. But that wasn't stated in the OP's question. Halbert White's context is the linear classical regression model where the $X_{i}$ are random with no particular distribution. I'm pretty sure that's what the OP was referring to. Note that the derivation below is identical to that for the fixed case. But we can agree to disagree. No problem.  When I have time,  I'll try to find something that one can actually read instead of borrow and squint. LOL.

Comment: I can't spend more time on this but the top of 874 ( second column ) in this, pretty much explains why one needs the convergence assumption. The expectation of error term and the $((X^{\prime}X)^{-1} X^{\prime})$ term needs to be zero.  https://connectjournals.com/file_full_text/3058402H_873-880.pdf

Comment: I can't claim that I follow it perfectly but here's a very nice cross validated thread where various people get into a lot of details. It's definitely not a straightforward topic. One thing I took from it and other things I glanced at is that : In the fixed case, we don't need the orthogonality assumption. It's implied by the other assumptions. In the stochastic case, we do need it. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/215230/what-are-the-differences-between-stochastic-and-fixed-regressors-in-linear-regre

Comment: @ Andrew : I  made a mistake in my earlier comment which may have caused you to read something else in halbert white's text. I should have said Theorem 2.12 on the bottom of page 17. My apologies and thanks for spurring this conversation. I never would have found the cross validated thread which I plan on going through carefully someday.

Answer (score 1):

One has
$$E(\hat \beta \mid X) = \beta+(X^TX)^{-1}X^TE(\varepsilon\mid X) = \beta$$
Thus $E(\hat \beta) = \beta$. Straightforward algebra then shows $$\hat \beta \hat \beta^T = \beta\beta^T+\beta\varepsilon^T X (X^TX)^{-1}+(X^TX)^{-1}X^T\varepsilon\beta^T+(X^TX)^{-1}X^T\varepsilon\varepsilon^TX(X^TX)^{-1}$$
It is easy to believe (with some abuse of notation) that $E(\varepsilon ^T X\mid X) = E(X^T\varepsilon \mid X) = 0$. Namely
$$ E(\hat \beta\hat \beta^T \mid X) = \beta \beta^T + \sigma^2(X^TX)^{-1} $$
Whence $\mathrm{Cov}(\hat \beta) = \sigma^2 E[(X^TX)^{-1}]$

Remark: One would expect that $$E(\varepsilon_1\mid \sigma(X_1,X_2)) = E(\varepsilon_1 \mid X_1)$$
The way to do it is to check it for rectangles $B = (X_1 \in B_1,X_2\in B_2) \in \sigma(X_1,X_2)$ and then apply a monotone class / $\pi-\lambda$ argument.